# Getting fields information using java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am working on this program which would print all the information related to an object, that information includes:

For each slice (class in the object hierarchy) in x:

- Print the class name of the slice.
- For each non-static field in that slice:

  - Print all the field modifiers followed by the field name.
  - Print the value of the field as follows:

    - If the field is null print null.
    - If the field is a primitive type print its value
    - If the field is a String print its value
    - If the field is an array:

      - Loop over the elements in the array
      - Print the index
      - Recursively print the details of the array item
    - Otherwise, recursively print the details of the field

I have pretty much printed all the information using the code below:

```
public void print(Object obj) {
        Class cl = obj.getClass();
        while(cl != null) {
            System.out.println("Class Name: " + cl.getName());
            Field[] fields = cl.getFields();
            System.out.println("FIELDS: ");
            for(int i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
                String modifier = Modifier.toString(fields[i].getModifiers());
                String name = fields[i].getName();
                System.out.print("Modifier: "+modifier+" Name: "+name+ "  ");
                try {
                    if(fields[i].get(cl) == null)
                        System.out.print("Value: NULL");
                } catch (        IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JCP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                if(fields[i].getType().isPrimitive())
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Value: " + fields[i].get(cl));
                } catch (        IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JCP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                if(fields[i].getType().isArray()) {
                    try {
                        Object[] object=(Object[])fields[i].get(obj);
                        System.out.print("Values: ");
                        for(int j=0;j<object.length;j++){
                            System.out.print(object[j].toString() + ",");
                        }   } catch (            IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(JCP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            cl = cl.getSuperclass();
        } 
    }
```

On testing this on the following class:

```
public class hello {
    private int privateField1;
    private long privateField2;
    public int publicField1;
    public int publicField2;

    public hello() {
    }


}
```

I got the following output:

```
Class Name: hello
FIELDS: 
Mar 10, 2014 2:54:36 PM JCP print
SEVERE: null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field hello.publicField1 to java.lang.Class
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
Modifier: public Name: publicField1  Modifier: public Name: publicField2  
Class Name: java.lang.Object
FIELDS: 

    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
    at JCP.print(JCP.java:211)
    at JCP.start(JCP.java:36)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)

Mar 10, 2014 2:54:36 PM JCP print
SEVERE: null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field hello.publicField1 to java.lang.Class
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
    at JCP.print(JCP.java:219)
    at JCP.start(JCP.java:36)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)

Mar 10, 2014 2:54:36 PM JCP print
SEVERE: null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field hello.publicField2 to java.lang.Class
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
    at JCP.print(JCP.java:211)
    at JCP.start(JCP.java:36)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)

Mar 10, 2014 2:54:36 PM JCP print
SEVERE: null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field hello.publicField2 to java.lang.Class
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
    at JCP.print(JCP.java:219)
    at JCP.start(JCP.java:36)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Mainly its throwing all the exceptions at "fields[i].get(cl)", kindly help me figuring out where is the problem in getting the field values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use:

```
fields[i].get(obj)
```

instead of:

```
fields[i].get(cl)
```

because you are trying to get the value of this particular instance of the class, not the class itself.

Comment: alright, but classes will keep on changing in the loop (upwards in hierarchy), and obj will be just one object of the initial class. I will have to make object of each class first or what?

Comment: @AbdulJabbar `obj` is an instance of the initial class, but it's also an instance of all the superclasses of this class, so you just use `obj` for everything, and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you help me in the part "if the field is String", can't find anyway to find that like isString().

Comment: @AbdulJabbar `if(fields[i].getType().equals(String.class))` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have few issues in that code in this part

```
if(fields[i].get(cl) == null) {
    System.out.print("Value: NULL");
}

if(fields[i].getType().isPrimitive()) {
    System.out.println("Value: " + fields[i].get(cl));
}

if(fields[i].getType().isArray()) {
    Object[] object=(Object[])fields[i].get(obj);
    System.out.print("Values: ");

    for(int j=0;j<object.length;j++){
        System.out.print(object[j].toString() + ",");
    }
}
```

Fist is that you call the method on type instance instead of class.

`fields[i].get(obj)` should be `fields[i].get(cl)` and you repeat that, when you check the value for private. Also you use to much invocation. You can simplify code readability if you assign the results to local variables.

```
public void print(Object obj) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        Class type = obj.getClass();

        while(type != null) {

            System.out.printf("Class Name: %s ", type.getName());
            System.out.println("FIELDS: ");

            for(Fiedl field : type.getFields()) {

                String modifier = Modifier.toString(field.getModifiers());

                String name = field.getName();

                System.out.printf("Modifiers: %s Name:%s\n",modifier,name);

                Object   fieldValue = field.get(obj);
                Class<?> filedType  = field.getType();
                String   printValue = null;

                if(fieldValue == null) {
                     printValue = "NULL";
                } else 
                if(fieldType.isArray()) {
                     printValue = Arrays.toString((Object[]) fieldValue);
                } else {
                     printValue = String.valueOf(fieldValue);                
                }

                System.out.printf("Value: %s",printValue);

            }
            System.out.println();
            type = type.getSuperclass();
        } 
    }
```